# Vue JS static link issue

Tags: javascript, routes, vue.js, vuejs2

I have Vue.js application (v2).

If I don't call the root of the site, the sub-links doesn't works.

Working example:

1. Go to: http://frontend-clickwash.azurewebsites.net
2. Go to http://frontend-clickwash.azurewebsites.net/login

If i go directly to: http://frontend-clickwash.azurewebsites.net/login

i receive error: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: Your server should be configured to respond with `index.html` for all requests including 404 errors. What's your server software?

Answer (score 0):

Your server should always respond, no matter what route is being requested, with your front-end application.

So this way when you try to access /login directly, your server will respond your front-end application entirely, then when your vue application ends loading, it will check which route is active, then render the proper component.